# Grails 2.4.4 - hibernate exception

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

1. when processing request: [GET] /sample/login/doLog the following error occour.
2. There is no column like email_Address in my db. but its says Unknown column 'user0_.email_address'

please help me guys.

Thanks in advance

```
    /**LoginController.groovy **/

    package sample

    import grails.converters.JSON

    class LoginController {

    LoginService loginService

    def doLog() {
        def res = loginService.doLogin1();
        render res as JSON
        }
    }

    /**  LoginService **/

    package sample

    import grails.transaction.Transactional
    import sample.User

    @Transactional
    class LoginService {

    def doLogin1() {
        def result = User.executeQuery("from User")
        return result
        }
    }

    /** Domain class User.groovy **/

    package sample
        class User {

            String emailAddress
            String userPasswd
            String payrollId
            String posLoginId
            String firstName
            String lastName
            String designation

        static mapping = {
                id name: "emailAddress", generator: "assigned"
                version false
            }

            static constraints = {
                emailAddress maxSize: 45
                userPasswd maxSize: 45
                payrollId nullable: true, maxSize: 20
                posLoginId nullable: true, maxSize: 10
                firstName maxSize: 45
                lastName nullable: true, maxSize: 45
                designation nullable: true, maxSize: 50
            }
        }




        Error |
        2015-10-24 17:46:27,431 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Unknown column 'user0_.email_address' in 'field list'
        Error |
        2015-10-24 17:46:27,493 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MySQLSyntaxErrorException occurred when processing request: [GET] /sample/login/doLog
        Unknown column 'user0_.email_address' in 'field list'. Stacktrace follows:
        Message: Unknown column 'user0_.email_address' in 'field list'
            Line | Method
        ->>   -2 | newInstance0                           in sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
        |     57 | newInstance                            in     ''
        |     45 | newInstance . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl
        |    526 | newInstance                            in java.lang.reflect.Constructor
        |   1002 | jlrConstructorNewInstance . . . . . .  in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
        |    377 | handleNewInstance                      in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
        |    360 | getInstance . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
        |    978 | createSQLException                     in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
        |   3887 | checkErrorPacket . . . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
        |   3823 | checkErrorPacket                       in     ''
        |   2435 | sendCommand . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
        |   2582 | sqlQueryDirect                         in     ''
        |   2530 | execSQL . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
        |   1907 | executeInternal                        in com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement
        |   2030 | executeQuery . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
        |    208 | getResultSet                           in org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher
        |   1953 | getResultSet . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.hibernate.loader.Loader
        |    802 | doQuery                                in     ''
        |    274 | doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections in     ''
        |   2542 | doList                                 in     ''
        |   2276 | listIgnoreQueryCache . . . . . . . . . in     ''
        |   2271 | list                                   in     ''
        |    459 | list . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader
        |    365 | list                                   in org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl
        |    196 | performList . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan
        |   1268 | list                                   in org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl
        |    102 | list . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl
        |    150 | doInHibernate                          in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.ExecuteQueryPersistentMethod$1
        |    411 | doExecute . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
        |    348 | executeFind                            in     ''
        |     88 | doInvokeInternal . . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.ExecuteQueryPersistentMethod
        |     79 | invoke                                 in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod
        |     72 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
        |    512 | executeQuery                           in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi
        |     -1 | executeQuery . . . . . . . . . . . . . in sample.User
        |     25 | $tt__doLogin1                          in sample.LoginService
        |     -1 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in eit.nvts.LoginService$_doLogin1_closure3
        |     -2 | invoke0                                in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
        |     57 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
        |     43 | invoke                                 in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
        |    606 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.reflect.Method
        |   1270 | jlrMethodInvoke                        in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
        |     90 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod
        |    324 | doMethodInvoke                         in groovy.lang.MetaMethod
        |   1207 | invokeMethod . . . . . . . . . . . . . in groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
        |   1110 | invokeMethod                           in groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass
        |   1016 | invokeMethod . . . . . . . . . . . . . in groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
        |    423 | call                                   in groovy.lang.Closure
        |     -1 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in eit.nvts.LoginService$_doLogin1_closure3
        |    439 | call                                   in groovy.lang.Closure
        |     -1 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in eit.nvts.LoginService$_doLogin1_closure3
        |     88 | doInTransaction                        in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2
        |    133 | execute . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate
        |     85 | execute                                in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate
        |     -1 | doLogin1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in eit.nvts.LoginService
        |     20 | doLog                                  in eit.nvts.LoginController
        |     -2 | invoke0 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
        |     57 | invoke                                 in     ''
        |     43 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
        |    606 | invoke                                 in java.lang.reflect.Method
        |   1270 | jlrMethodInvoke . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
        |    154 | invoke                                 in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper
        |    375 | handleAction . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper
        |    252 | executeAction                          in     ''
        |    205 | handleURI . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
        |    126 | handleURI                              in     ''
        |     72 | handleRequest . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController
        |     50 | handle                                 in org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter
        |    347 | doDispatch . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet
        |    870 | doService                              in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        |    961 | processRequest . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
        |    852 | doGet                                  in     ''
        |    620 | service . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
        |    837 | service                                in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
        |    727 | service . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
        |    303 | internalDoFilter                       in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
        |    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
        |     52 | doFilter                               in org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter
        |    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
        |    208 | doFilter                               in     ''
        |    198 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
        |     63 | doFilter                               in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
        |    344 | invokeDelegate . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        |    261 | doFilter                               in     ''
        |    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
        |    208 | doFilter                               in     ''
        |    101 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
        |    241 | internalDoFilter                       in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
        |    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
        |    101 | doFilter                               in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
        |    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
        |    208 | doFilter                               in     ''
        |    101 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
        |    241 | internalDoFilter                       in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
        |    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
        |    748 | invoke                                 in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
        |    486 | processRequest . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
        |    411 | doForward                              in     ''
        |    338 | forward . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
        |    178 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo        in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils
        |    144 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo . . .  in     ''
        |    135 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo        in     ''
        |    216 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter
        |    107 | doFilter                               in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
        |    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
        |    208 | doFilter                               in     ''
        |     69 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter
        |    107 | doFilter                               in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
        |    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
        |    208 | doFilter                               in     ''
        |     67 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
        |    107 | doFilter                               in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
        |    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
        |    208 | doFilter                               in     ''
        |     88 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        |    107 | doFilter                               in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
        |    344 | invokeDelegate . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        |    261 | doFilter                               in     ''
        |    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
        |    208 | doFilter                               in     ''
        |    220 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
        |    122 | invoke                                 in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve
        |    171 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve
        |    103 | invoke                                 in org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve
        |    116 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve
        |    408 | service                                in org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter
        |   1070 | process . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor
        |    611 | process                                in org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler
        |    314 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor
        |   1145 | runWorker                              in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
        |    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
        |     61 | run                                    in org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable
        ^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 3):

> There is no column like email_Address in my db. but its says Unknown
>   column 'user0_.email_address'

You just described what the exact problem is. You appear to have added an emailAddress field to your domain object, so Hibernate is expecting there to be an email_address column on the table now. You need to update your database schema somehow to match your domain objects.

You might want to look into the [Grails Database Migration plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/database-migration).